# jwPlayer: When using IE10, can't get the length with the function getPlaylist()

Tags: internet-explorer-10, jwplayer

I want to get the length of the playList, so I using the code below, it can work at FF, Chrome, IE8, except IE10.

Here is my code

```
var playListLength = jwplayer('jwplayer249').getPlaylist().length;
for (var i = playListLength - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    var htmlSpan = '<span class="">' + i +'</span>';                                   
    $(".ip_fs_prev").after(htmlSpan); 
 } ;
```

at IE10 it return undefined attributes.

Comment: Do you have a link to where you tried to embed this?

Comment: No, in my code, I get the length, just want to show how many file in my Playlist, so we can choose which one to play. And also, show the current item's title in the frontend.
        var playListLength = jwplayer('jwplayer249').getPlaylist().length;
        for (var i = playListLength - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            var htmlSpan = '<span class="">' + i + '</span>';
            $(".ip_fs_prev").after(htmlSpan);
        }
        ;

Comment: Can you put something up if possible?